# Populating dropdowns in Blazor/Razor using data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am trying to populate dropdown lists in a Razor page using data from SQL Server to make sure that the parameters I am using to pull data from my main table are always current.  I have 5 dropdown lists with IDs and a function to add the items to the dropdowns but Visual Studio is telling me that the IDs don't exist.  How can I access the IDs in the function to populate the lists?  I have tried putting the code on the main HTML page and in the code behind file.  I tried to include the code but there is too much code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Formulated this way, this question can hardly be answered. What technology do you use to retrieve data from SQL Server? What's the exact message saying "the IDs don't exist"? Please show some code.

Comment: For some tips about how to provide useful code, check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Almost none of what you just said sounds like a Blazor page.  In Blazor, you don't use IDs to identify objects and add things to them.  You use markup to include components, and boolean comparisons to determine whether to display each, and foreach to iterate through lists.

For example:

```
@if (IDList is not null){
    <select>
    foreach (var item in IDList){
        <option value="@item">@item.ToString()</option>
    }
}

@code {
    List<int> IDList {get; set;}

    override async Task OnInitialized(){
        IDList = DB.DoSomeLoading();
    }
}
```

Nowhere in there do I need to make or know the ID of any object in my markup.

Comment: I am trying to convert a web app that I did using HTML and C# in VS to be hosted on a Blazor site.  One of my dropdowns is defined as:  <select ID="Jurisdiction" runat="server"></select>  and I try to access it by:  Jurisdiction.Items.Add("All");

Comment: Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have to let go of the idea of objects, and focus more on data.  Web Forms had to render an entire page at once and send it all-- so building static objects in that way made sense.  But Blazor doesn't really need to post back, and data is much more dynamic.  See the example I gave here and let me know what's missing for you.  I'll be happy to elaborate.

Comment: When I added the OnInitialized line I get virtual or abstract members cannot be private.  How do I fix it?  Is there a using directive that I need to add?

Comment: If you start by typing "override," VS should pop-up your options.  But anyway, you can use `protected override` for your keywords.

Comment: I added the <select> item like you suggests but it is saying @item does not exist.